# How many people per day view Christianity stack?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, statistics

Does the stack have data to indicate the number of hits per day on Christianity section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More detailed traffic stats can be found at [QuantCast](https://www.quantcast.com/christianity.stackexchange.com#trafficCard).  Total visits in the last month was 800.3k, consistent with the above figure of 26k+/day on average.  Looks like it was varied from 22k-32k in that period.  The record was set on April 5, 2015 (Easter) with 45.2k visitors.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a general idea of usage for all SE sites by [sorting the site list by traffic](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic). Over the last two weeks the median visits per day for C.SE has been 26,438.