# In terms of interest/activity on C.SE; are we growing, dying, thriving?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I have no way of seeing, let alone analyzing, metrics (that I'm aware of).

The activity on C.SE seems rather tepid. Has this always been the case? Does it have a positive tangent to the curve? Curious...

Comment: I don't look at the metrics that are provided to me as a mod near as often as I should, but my opinion is this site gurgles and churns in fits and starts (if that helps) and it does so consistently.  We really should have a contest one of these days.

Comment: Thanks. By 'contest' what precisely are you referring to; please?

Comment: Some of the other sites have unofficial contests where a meta-post gets tagged and the rules are in there, and then we set up some sort of an answer to the meta post as a leader-board and there is much rejoicing.  I'm not sure it would be at all a popular idea on _this_ site where things appear to have more gravitas than say, [scifi.se].   But I would love a Luther vs Bellarmine tag throwdown.   Maybe a Chesterton vs Lewis throwdown would be more appropriate (as most of us like both those guys)

Comment: The site moves consistently for at least three years now, in my observation. If you're comparing to Stack overflow, *then* you might use the word tepid.

Comment: See also [Year in Review 2016](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6149/21576) (and particularly the comments on the answer) and [How many people per day view Christianity stack?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5781/21576)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This query from SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/christianity/query/654457/number-of-questions-per-month-posted-to-the-site#graph) shows how this site has gathered questions over the years. The number of non-deleted questions per month (the blue line) has remained fairly stable, with only a slight decline. This is to be expected, as there are only so many big questions which almost everyone wonders about. We continue to get lots of questions however, and there's nothing to make us think we've asked and answered all that can be asked and answered.

[image: Graph from SEDE]

Comment: Thanks @curiousdannii. Is the 'Gold' [Questions w/Deleted] representing questions that had deleted answers? If that is the case, then I would have to conclude that the widening gap (gold/blue), corresponds to more aggressive moderation from 1/1/13' to 1/1/15'. The number of Deleted Questions corresponds with this as well.  The interesting thing is that Closed Questions seemed to have normalized, roughly at the beginning of 2015. Interesting also, is the convergence of the Deleted/Non-Deleted derivatives (blue, red) at the same point (beginning of 2015). Thanks for the metrics.

Comment: I think the gold/yellow is the total number of questions, including deleted questions. Answers aren't included in any of the numbers.